# How to check if an object is null or not?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I´m trying to do a condition if array nr#1 of xmlHttp.responseText is null.
But I can not get it work. Don´t know what´s wrong..

**From php** I send array using json_encode.
And in javascipt I use JSON.parse() methode to parse array.

There´re only 2 strings in this array ["", ""]

And I´m trying to detect if the first array is null so alert something.

**Let´s see my code :**

```
var str=xmlHttp.responseText;
var res=JSON.parse(str);
```

And the following lines I have tried but none of them ´s working !

```
if (res[0]=null) {
alert('hey, it´s null');
}

AND

if (res[0]==null) {
alert('hey, it´s null');
}

AND

if (res[0]=="null") {
alert('hey, it´s null');
}

AND

if (res[0]=="") {
alert('hey, it´s null');
}


I have used PHP to echo the code json and i get:

["null",""]
```

So what´s wrong actually ?

Comment: You should never have a string with a value of `"null"`.  You should use actual `null`s instead.

Comment: Actually it´s number sorry if I say it wrong.

Comment: The first *if* does not work the way you want it to do. It sets the value instead of checking it. Use two equal signs (`==`)!

Comment: you are missing a an "=" in the first condition, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(res)` right after you JSON.parse it?

Comment: Hi, thanks.
But how to get it work actually  :S

Comment: @PoramatFin If you would respond to Jonathan Crowe's comment, for example.

Comment: @kangoroo he said he "tried" that, not that he is currently using it. His later examples show a more apt comparison `==`

Comment: Hi I did not use console.log(res) I´m very new with that.
But I have echo it in php and i get ["null",""]

Comment: @PoramatFin Place `console.log(res)` at the top of your JavaScript file/script block. Then, go into your browser's dev console (probably `F12`) and copy the log message.

Comment: you just enter console.log(str) in your javascript, not so hard.

Comment: Finding out what javascript is woking with is much more helpful than what PHP echos. Look into your browsers developer tools (i recommend chrome or firefox) so we can better assist you with your Questions. It's also just a good thing to start using if you are going to be doing any JS work

Comment: Hi the reason i can not do that is it´s inside a very complicated ajax which have other thing to do. It´s hard it just take this and get all.

Comment: You can do it. Directly after the line `var res=JSON.parse(str);` add the following line of code `console.log(res);` and tell us what the console output is

Answer (score 1):

If you get the json data :

```
["null",""]
```

which implies

```
$data = array(
    0 => "null",
    1 => ""
);

$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;                 ---> this result like yours....["null",""]
echo "<br />";
$res =  json_decode($json);   ----> you must decode your Json first...

echo $res[0];                -----> this code result is "null" like you wanted...
```

The below statement will let you know if the object is empty.

```
if (res[0]==null) {             -----> it always result "[" not the data "null"....
alert('hey, it´s null');
}
```

So, firstly you must decode the json data and next you check the object.

Comment: Eko Junaidi Salam  Hi; thank you for your answer. 
I have a reason that I can not use json_decode method. It´s all about the other functions. would be nice if I can do it in javascript. This is the last line.

Comment: you're welcome....
you can do it in javascript using JQuery JsonParse... do you use it ?

Comment: I have too complicated function inside, Difficult to explain. But I have given up.